# How do I convert width and height (in pixels) to columns for use with the python library pyte?

Tags: python, terminal, pyside

**Background**

I'm working on a graphical ssh client in Python.  I'm using PySide for the GUI, a fork of Paramiko for the ssh interaction and a library called Pyte for the terminal emulation.

**The problem**

I can't figure out how to correctly resize the pyte terminal in relation to the PySide QTextEdit being resized.  I can only seem to get the width and height of the QTextEdit in pixels, not columns and rows which is required by the pyte library's Screen.resize() function.

Is there anyway to either 1. get the column and line count for the QTextEdit or 2. convert the pixel width and height to columns and lines in a manner that is accurate across all systems?

**Proposed Solution**

Replace the QTextEdit.resizeEvent() function with a custom resize event handler which will call the Screen.resize() function of pyte to resize the terminal to match the new size of the QTextEdit widget.

If there is an easier solution I'm very open to ideas.

Comment: Terminal fonts are always of a fixed size, so I suspect it's just a matter of multiplying or dividing by the appropriate dimensions.

Comment: I've been playing all night with taking font point sizes and converting them to pixel sizes and dividing by QWidget geometry height and widths to determine columns and lines but it isn't 100% accurate thus far, although for columns it appears to almost always be 1 character beyond where I need to be.  Unfortunately a QFontMetric object requires either the maxWidth() (which is too large a lot of the time) or a unicode character passed to width() in order to convert points to pixels (thus why things aren't always 100% accurate if I use a few characters that are larger than my chosen character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I ended up pulling font metrics and geometry information for the widget I was working with (QTextEdit).  I then implemented a custom resize event for the QTextEdit which handled catching states on different events that caused an update (see the first if statement in my resizeConsoleEvent in the code block below), then, calculated the new available columns and lines and passed those to the ssh object (self.shell below).

**The Code**

```
def resizeConsoleEvent(self, resizeObject):
    if not self.keyPressDown and not self.blockResizing:
        # calculate maximum columns and lines based on a '|' character
        font = self.ui.console.currentFont()
        fmetric = QtGui.QFontMetrics(font)
        fontPixelWidth = fmetric.width("|")
        fontPixelHeight = fmetric.height()
        availableWidthPixels = int(self.ui.console.geometry().width())
        availableHeightPixels = int(self.ui.console.geometry().height())
        # Calculate columns and lines w/ adjustments for rounding
        self.consoleColumns = int(availableWidthPixels / fontPixelWidth) + 1
        self.consoleLines = int(availableHeightPixels / fontPixelHeight) - 3

        # resize the pyte screen I'm using with the calculated information
        self.shell.resizeConsole(self.consoleLines, self.consoleColumns)

        # block double resize event
        self.keyPressDown = False
        return False
    else:

        return True
```